# Having installed wxWidgets-devel with MacPorts, what should I add to PATH?

Tags: path, macports, wxwidgets

I've used Macports on Snow Leopard to install wxWidgets-devel, hoping then to succesfully
install wxHaskell...

I have to Check your path to make sure you are using your wxWidgets and not the default Mac one"

port contents wxWidgets-devel says I have a lot of wx stuff installed
in /opt/local/bin (wx-config, wxrc)
and /opt/local/include/wx-2.9/wx...
and /opt/local/lib/libwx_baseu...

What should I add to PATH?

Answer (score 2):

You should have wx-config script available after installation. Try to run

> wx-config --cxxflags

or

> wx-config --libs

The first one returns all parameters for compiler, second one - for linker.

Comment: Does this mean I should include the location of wx-config in the PATH?

Comment: No, as far as I understand, the script will be placed to your system folder (not quite sure but it will be smth like /usr/local/bin) and will be available by default. You can try to search for wx-config after installing wxWidgets using MacPorts and then see where it exists.